# How to print contents of an HTML element in MacGap?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview, macgap

I'm creating a WebView app with [MacGap2](https://github.com/MacGapProject/MacGap2) and I'd like to be able to print the contents of an HTML element (with a print preview like you would see in Safari/Preview/etc).

I've been looking at [WebUIDelegate's webView:printFrameView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebUIDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:printFrameView:) as well as [Printing Entire Contents of WebView in Cocoa, Not Just Displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529126/printing-entire-contents-of-webview-in-cocoa-not-just-displayed) - but I'm having a hard time putting it all together as I'm new to Objective-C/Cocoa.

If I wanted a method like this (options not necessary if print preview works):

```
MacGap.print([HTMLelement], [options]);

// Example usage
var el = document.getElementById('view');

// Or if not element, send as HTML string? (with inline CSS)
// el = el.innerHTML;

MacGap.print(el, { printBackgrounds: true, landscape: false });
```

What would I need to add to my MacGap Classes/Commands?

**App.h:**

```
- (void) print:(NSString*)printString;
```

**App.m:**

```
- (void) print:(NSString*)printString {
    // ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have experience with MacGap2 and I tested this on a uiwebview not a webview, but I think it should still work to get the html string from the webview.

```
- (void) print:(NSString*)printString 
{
     NSString * pstrViewHTML= [myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"function getView(){return document.getElementById('view');} getView();"];
    // Do something with html string.
}
```